# If $f([1,2,1])=[1,2], f([1,1,3]) =[0,3]$ and $ f([2,3,-1]) =[1,1],$ then find$ f([0, 2, 5])$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

please we need help with something like that:

We have given linear mapping $$f: R^3 \to R^2, f([1,2,1])=[1,2], f([1,1,3]) =[0,3], f([2,3,-1]) =[1,1].$$

We need to know: $$ f([0, 2, 5]) = [?,?]$$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ such that $$[0, 2, 5]=a_1[1,2,1]+a_2[1,1,3]+a_3[2,3,-1].$$
Since $T$ is linear, we have 
$$T([0, 2, 5])=a_1T([1,2,1])+a_2T([1,1,3])+a_3T([2,3,-1]).$$

Comment: Is result [5,4] ?